# How to import anything to js file that connected to html from js which not connected

Tags: javascript, html

I have Main.html and simple.js connected to Main.html. I want to import some variables from out.js to simple.js. I dont want to connect out.js to html. I tried to write basic import and export code, but i had and error, also changed type of simple.js from

```
<script src="simple.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="simple.js" type="module"></script>
```

and still not working, I know it is possible, but I don't know how.

I tried require too, and it didn't work.

Because out.js it a node.js file, that starting whole html to the browser, I connected mongodb to this out.js so I can't connect it to html. And also I need somehow transport data that was taken from mongodb to simple.js that connected to my html

Comment: Because out.js its file with node js , that starting whole html to the browser, I connected mongodb to this out.js so I cant connect it ot html. And also I need somehow transport data that was taken from mongodb to simple.js that connected to my html . I hope u will understand me ))